# How can I make the rule engine always choose the rule with higher Salience?

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, drools-planner, drools-flow

I´m using Salience to make the priority of each rule, but when I fireAllRules, it doesn't always choose the rule with higher Salience. How can I make the rule engine always choose the rule with higher Salience?

Output

```
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   10
Positon1   Salience:   10
Positon2   Salience:   10
Rule Number:0
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   10
Positon2   Salience:   10
Rule Number:1
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   9
Positon2   Salience:   10
Rule Number:1
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   8
Positon2   Salience:   10
Rule Number:2
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   8
Positon2   Salience:   9
Rule Number:2
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   8
Positon2   Salience:   8
Rule Number:2
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 8, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   8
Positon2   Salience:   7
Rule Number:2
pleasant:false    activation:false   context:working   multitasking:true    state:stuck
[9, 8, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Positon0   Salience:   9
Positon1   Salience:   8
Positon2   Salience:   6
Rule Number:0
```

Actionlistener that fire the rules

```
simula.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FactHandle fact1;
                fact1= new SimulaRegras(pleas, act, context.getText(), mtask, state.getText(),sal);

                ksession.insert(fact1);
                ksession.fireAllRules(1);

            }

        }
                );
```

Drools Main

```
public class DroolsTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            KieContainer kc = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
            new DroolsTest().init(kc);
        }

        public DroolsTest() {
        }

        public void init(final KieContainer kc) {
            KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("ksession-rule");

            TeleInterface t = new TeleInterface(ksession);
            FactHandle fact2;
            fact2 = ksession.insert(t);
        }
    }
```

Rule Struct

```
    rule "Num1"
            salience(sr.gSal(0))

        when 

            t: TeleInterface ()
            sr: SimulaRegras(pleasant == false && activation == false && context == "working", multitask == true, state == "stuck")

        then
            t.gMap.setEnabled(true);
            t.gMap.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            t.background.setIcon(new ImageIcon("ponto.png"));
            t.action("gMap", false);
            t.infoBox("optimization", "add", "Adicionar ponto no grid map e fornecer o caminho");
            t.sSal(0);
end
```

Comment: You are showing some output which could be made anywhere, anyhow. You are showing some code to insert a fact which could contain anything. Nobody can tell from these incoherent snippets what happens in your program.

Comment: The issue is when I use fireallrules(1). When I use it the second time it doesn't see all the rules. If I just use fireallrules() it always runs the rule with higher salience.
How can I fireallrules more than once and choose just therule with the higher salience?

Comment: This is unclear, please provide full code demonstrating the problem. - Any call of fireAllRules() with or without a parameter will always fire the rule with the highest salience on the current agenda.

Comment: https://github.com/ljpms/ljpm.git

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve but using salience is not the way to go. Salience based on a value in a fact attribute can be replaced by logic, i.e., by checking that there's no other fact of this  type with a higher value of this attribute. Moreover, modifying the attribute providing salience is not a good idea since Drools will not reevaluate the salience.

I'm not going to investigate this any further as a user interface (`TeleInterface`) doesn't describe what was actually inserted.

Comment: Is there no way to reevaluate the salience every time insert a new fact?

Comment: I inserted (TeleInterface) so I could change the interface through the rules